# My HTML5 web app crashes and I have no clue how to debug

Tags: javascript, debugging, web-applications, html, canvas

I have written a word game using HTML5 canvas tag and a little bit of audio. I developed the application on the chrome web browser on a linux system. Recently during the testing phase it was tried on safari 5.0.3 on Mac and the webpage froze. Not just the canvas element, but interactive element on the page froze. I have at some times experienced this problem on google chrome when I was developing but since the console did not throw any error before this happened, I did not give it much credence. Now as per requirements I am supposed to support both chrome and safari but this dismal performance on safari has left me shocked and I cannot see what error can be thrown which might lead to such a situation. Worse yet the CPU usage on using this application peaks to 70-80percent on my 2yr old macbook running ubuntu... I can only but pity the person who uses mac to operate this app, which undoubtedly is a heavier OS. Could someone help me out with a place I can start with to find out what exactly is causing this issue.

I have run profiles on this webapp on google chromes console and noticed that in the heap spanshot value increases steadily with the playing of the game, specifically (root) value which jumps up by 900 counts. Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT: I don't know if this helps, but I have noticed that even on refreshing the page after the app becomes unresponsive the page reloads and I am still not able to interact with the page elements but the tab scroll bar continues to work and I can see my application window completely. So to summaries the tab stops accepting any sort of user interaction inside the page.

Edit2: Nop. It doesn't work still... The app crashes on double click on the canvas element. The console is not throwing any errors either! =/ I have noticed this problem is isolated only to safari!

Edit3: Okay, so I performed some other tests today. I isolated the HTML5 widget and its HTML data only and ran it on safari locally to reproduce the error. Alas it works well! So I tried playing the game from my server without Facebook integration, and it works fine again! So The issue crops up only on safari on MAC OSX, while the widget is on Facebook canvas as a Facebook application. I am very hard-pressed to come up with a reduced test case scenario for this app... =/ It gets weirder, the game works well on safari for windows. Also after the tab freezes the other tabs continue to be responsive and well working. This tab too closes on clicking the close button and stuff, but if I load another page on this same tab after its frozen the page loads in the tab canvas, but I cannot interact with it. Not even google.com! So I am sure there is no bug with my game but its a safari bug... Will soon file a bug report, thanks for all the help people... :)

Comment: Install firefox and then install firebug: http://getfirebug.com, then activate firebug, this should be a bit better at highlighting any error in your JavaScript

Comment: I don't have js errors, this problem is unique to safari.. Interestingly it seems like I have discovered a bug with safari itself.. I will be doing a little more digging into it... I use Google chrome inspect element, i find it much better than firefox, and also my code is not supported by firefox till 4 beta...

Answer (score 3):

What you should do, in one sentence: **Reproduce the problem with as little code as possible.**

Start removing parts of your app until you find nothing that can be removed while still preserving the error. Start by throwing out external resources (css, images, etc) and leave just the html and javascript. Try removing the audio. Try removing as much gaming logic as possible. Try removing all user input code.

If this truly is a bug in Safari itself and not in your code, it should be possible to create a **very** small code example. Until you have that, saying "my web app doesn't work in safari", without any details or examples, will get you nowhere.

Comment: Hi so I tried as you suggested, and actually have been on it since yesterday after I chatted with some people on the webkit IRC. Turns out I cannot reproduce the bug unless its via the Facebook canvas and on safari on MAC. This is weird coz I don't really know what is it with Facebook that causes my app to freeze the safari tab. I think I will file a bug report with my app link as it is. I am sure its not my apps fault, coz after the tab freezes even if I load google.com in the tab, the page loads by I cannot interact with any component of the page...